# Which application is this icon? it looks like a paw

Tags: mac, applications

[image]

Which application is this? I tried using Google image search to identify this application but was not able to.

Comment: what does it do? what happens if your right click on it?

Comment: I got the icon from this [forum](http://forums.macrumors.com/showpost.php?p=17290283&postcount=6)

Comment: This is the menu bar icon for Growl.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is for [Growl](http://growl.info) a popular notification system before Apple created the Notification Center. You will find a panel in the System Preferences that controls it.